# Teaching security concepts

Tags: certificates, x.509, kerberos

I think it would be nice to teach security concepts by giving practical examples. I am looking for some practical cases for x509 certificates, kerberos and SET.

How could I know an ecommerse site uses SET? Or is it the defacto standard?

How could I explain kerberos from a practical view point

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Kerberos

The best example of explaining Kerberos from a practical viewpoint I've ever come across, is Bill Bryant's [Designing an Authentication System:
a Dialogue in Four Scenes](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/dialogue.html). Originally intended to provide an understanding of the conceptual ideas in Kerberos, as a way to promote implemenations of KerberosV4, it does a decent job, and is quite amusing if you ask me.

---

### 2. SET

SET is *not* a de-facto standard, although intended and promoted as such during development. Even VISA, one of the sponsors and heavy proponents of SET, now promotes newer and more modern security standards for e-commerce.

---

### 3. X.509

The first practical case of X.509 certificates that comes to mind, is the widespread use of SSL/TLS to encrypt data transactions on websites over HTTPS

Comment: I always liked the idea of the e-wallet aspect of SET.  Not especially flexible so likely one of several reasons why it wasn't adopted.

Answer (score 2):

[Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) is a protocol for making authentication servers work. Microsoft's [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) uses Kerberos for all authentication purposes, so wherever there are Windows machines "in a domain" (as per Microsoft terminology, and as opposed to a "workgroup") then there is some Kerberos at work. A two-line summary of Kerberos is the following:

> Every machine trusts the Kerberos server. The Kerberos server authenticates users, and give them *tickets* which they then show to the other machines. Tickets are limited in time and scope.

[X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) is a standard format for *digital certificates*, which bind identities to public keys. X.509 works when applied to a specific domain through a *profile*; the profile tries to narrow down the wide possibilities of X.509 into a workable set of options. The profile for "the Internet" is [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) and its most visible and widespread application is the issuance of certificates for SSL servers. Whenever you connect your browser to an `https://` Web site, then X.509 certificates are at work.

[SET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Electronic_Transaction) was another X.509 profile. It was rather thorough in that it was making X.509 much more simple, by removing hordes of useless options; and it also defined a few extensions which were generally needed. However, commercial success and scientific rationality have never been the same thing; SET never became a "de-facto standard" and is all but abandoned nowadays.

For teaching material, be sure to read the [X.509 style guide](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epgut001/pubs/x509guide.txt) from Peter Gutmann. Students love sarcasm and jokes.